# Bind an Array of Array ob objects

Tags: angular

In my component, I have an array of rows which is dynamically populated with data from back-end

```
this.rows = []; // somehow put data inside
```

in every there is another element which is also an array of columns, which are also generated by back-end.

```
const row = {
      ColorId: 0,
      SizeId: 0,
      Quantity: 0,
      Fields: this.Product.Personalizations.map(p => {
        return {
          Value: '',
          ID: p.ID,
          Required: p.Required,
          Price: p.Price,
          Description: p.Description,
          Name: p.Name
        }
      })
    };

    this.rows.push(row);
```

I'm trying to bind each `Field` to an Input like this

```
<div class="bulk-order-row"
                 [ngClass]="{'active-bulk-row': editingOnMobile}"
                 *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index;">
...
                <div class="col-personalization" *ngFor="let field of row.Fields">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="hidden-md-up">{{field.Name}}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-alt" [required]="field.Required"
                      [(ngModel)]="field.Value" name="{{field.Name}}" id="{{field.ID}}">
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Seems like the fields are bound properly, but each time I append a new row all of the input fields become blank? If I check the actual values in `this.rows` I see they are in there.  Why the `input` become blank?

Comment: Might be related to `this.Product.Personalizations.map(p => {` being re-evaluated. A Plunker would be helpful to investigate.

Comment: here is the minimal Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/nm3y6MrR4kh0n8Sq6XwU
the way I see it, the problem is created by [required]. Click [AddRow] fill some values, then [Add row] again, fields values are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by all inputs in one row getting the same name.
Adding the index (`idx`) to the name fixes the issue:

```
  <tr *ngFor='let r of rows let idx=index'>
    <td>
      <input type='text' [(ngModel)]="r.quantity" name='quantity'>
    </td>
    <td *ngFor='let p of r.props'>
      <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='p.value' name='{{p.name}}{{idx}}' [id]='p.id'
        >
    </td>
  </tr>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bu9cftTs42gbn4NZ16NG?p=preview)